# Are there other ways to print out debugging messages without line-breaking the content in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there are many other ways to print out debugging messages without line-breaking the content:

```
  (function(){
          var r="";
          console.log("start: ");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                        console.log(i + " ");; //this will line-break the content
        }

        console.log("finish");


})();
```

---

**This one will not break the content:**** However I've to add all the result in one variable and then at the end print out the whole content, wondering if there are other ways to print out directly inside the LOOP without line-breaking the content...

THANKS

```
  (function(){
          var r="";
          console.log("start: ");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                       r+= (i + " "); //this will NOT break the content
        }
        console.log(r);
        console.log("finish");


})();
```

Comment: I've wondered this, and would love an answer.  Automatic adding of carriage returns, new-lines etc. is a pet-peeve of mine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need. `console` object has many methods, not only `log()`.

You can place all your data inside some object and call `console.dir(someObj)` for example, etc.

More info you can find on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console)

Comment: can't find any method helping me with more solutions? :(

Answer (score 0):

- You could make your own "`console`", using a textarea.
- You could add values to an array (`debugMessages.push(i)`) then join them (`debugMessages.join(" ")`)

Comment: You can pass multiple parameters to the `console.log`, which, when viewed all appear on the same line. If you built up the array, you could do `console.log.apply(null, debugMessages);`